# insert an image in kentico cms

Tags: asp.net, image, file-upload, image-uploading, kentico

I use Kentico CMS v5.5.3996 R2. I have a custom table with a column with below characteristics:
Attribute type: "Text" 
Field type :"image selection"
I have created an alternative form for this table (for insert) and show it in live site. My problem is that this "Image selection" shows all the images in kentico (It's good for administrator but not for users). Is there any other Field type for this purpose? (like avatar selector)

(Of course I decided to create a handy form (web user control) for insert, but my new problem is that " how to save image in kentico?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have decided to write your own control you can find great examples of how to save image in:

```
CMS\CMSModules\Content\Controls\Attachments\DirectFileUploader\DirectFileUploaderControl.ascx.cs
```

There are examples of storing content files, meta files, attachments and physical files.

Comment: thx a lot, following file helps a lot too: '~\CMSModules\Content\Controls\Attachments\FileUpload.ascx.cs'